# How to Skip remaining test case and move to next test case if the element is disabled

Tags: python, robotframework

I want to move the execution to next test case if the element is disabled it should log the whether the element is enabled or disable If it is enabled then continue with the test case (remaining code)and if it is disabled then move to next test case skip the remaining code in test case
for example:

```
TC01
    Element Should Be Enabled  ${options}#if not skip the remaing code and go to next test case
    Click Element  ${abc}
TC02
     Element Should Be Enabled  ${options}#if enabled continue with the remaing code
    Click Element  ${abc}
```

How can I do this in robot framework? can we skip the reaming part of test case if any condition in test case not satisfied??

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built in `Skip` and `Skip If` keywords for that one. See documentation for them here http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Skip

Example

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation   Example test cases

*** Test Cases ***
TC01
    ${options}  Set Variable  True
    Log  Variable options is ${options}, skipping test  console=True
    Skip If  ${options}
    Log  This code is not executed
TC02
    Run Keyword If  ${options}  MY_CONDITIONAL_KEYWORD

*** Keywords ***
MY_CONDITIONAL_KEYWORD
    Log  This code is executed  console=True
```

This outputs

```
Test :: Example test cases                                                    
==============================================================================
TC01                                                                  .Variable options is True, skipping test
TC01                                                                  | SKIP |
True
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TC02                                                                  This code is executed
TC02                                                                  | PASS |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test :: Example test cases                                            | PASS |
2 tests, 1 passed, 0 failed, 1 skipped
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. this will skip the test case write? but i want to log whether the element is enabled or not and in log file and if the element is enabled continue with the test case and if disabled move to next test case and if possible can you please show with the code how can i use this

Comment: @MachindraKale , I updated my answer with an example, hope that helps. If so please accept the answer, cheers!